How to decompose vectors with spanning sets that are not frames?
Consider a sequence $G\subset\mathcal H$ in a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal H$.
It is well-known that when $G$ is a frame we can decompose (not necessarily uniquely) arbitrary $v\in\mathcal H$ in terms of elements of $G$.
Furthermore, on account of the fact that frames guarantee the existence of a well-defined analysis operator
$$T:\mathcal H\to\ell^2: v\mapsto (\langle v, e_n\rangle)_{n\in\mathbb{N} },$$
we know that the coefficients obtained decomposing arbitrary vectors in terms of frame elements are $\ell^2$ sequences.
In finite dimensions, a finite sequence is a frame iff it has a lower frame bound and iff it spans the space (see e.g. this post).
An example of a sequence that spans $\mathbb{R}^2$ but is not a frame — because it lacks an upper frame bound — is $G=\{(1,0)\}\cup\{(0,1/n)\}_{n\ge1}$.
In this case it doesn't seem like there's too many issues with decomposing vectors in terms of $G$, e.g. by simply only using the first two components of it, which are an orthonormal basis.
For example, $G\equiv \{ e_n/n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N} }$ is not a frame on account of it not having a lower frame bound, but as mentioned in
(Casazza and Lynch, 1509.07347) it spans the space, as its orthogonal complement is $\{0\}$.
This example is also mentioned in this other post.
Its analysis operator would be $Tx=(\frac{x_n}{n})_n$, which is bounded and maps $T:\mathcal H\to\ell^2$.
Its synthesis operator is
$$T^*:\ell^2\to\mathcal H:c\mapsto \sum_n c_n \frac{e_n}{n},$$
also bounded.
However, the corresponding frame operator is
$$S = \sum_n \frac{e_n e_n^*}{n^2}, \qquad
S^{-1} = \sum_n n^2 \, e_n e_n^*.$$
So $S$ is bounded but not bounded-below, and correspondingly its inverse $S^{-1}$ isn't bounded (as an operator in $\ell^2$).
Can I simply interpret unboundedness as telling me that the coefficients associated to many vectors are not in $\ell^2$? For example,
$S^{-1}(1/n)_n=(n)_n\notin\ell^2$.
So maybe $S^{-1}$ is well-defined as a linear operator if I extend its image to the space of all sequences (not sure how to talk about boundedness if I do this though)? I find this a bit odd, and haven't seen it discussed anywhere.
A different example like $G\equiv \{n e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N} }$ will behave even worse: in this case $G$ isn't a Bessel sequence (i.e. lacks an upper frame bound) and thus even the analysis operator isn't bounded. Still, it spans the space so every vector should be decomposable via its elements. So what gives? What does the unboundedness of these operators imply?
More generally, what happens to decomposition coefficients when using a sequence that's not a frame? Can we still savage at least some of the apparatus of frame theory, somehow still using frame operators to extract coefficients, even though the object are unbounded and thus not everywhere defined?

I asked a related question on MO here.

From your opening paragraph, I'm guessing that your unstated intent is to consider only separable Hilbert spaces?

@LeeMosher yes indeed, thanks for pointing it out, I edited the post

If you change $e_n/n$ to $ne_n$, then you get a (densely) spanning set whose associated analysis operator is not bounded (in fact, since the analysis operator is always closed, it is not everywhere defined in this case). For a spanning sequence, it is a frame iff the analysis operator is everywhere defined (equivalently bounded) and its range is closed. $e_n/n$ violates the closed range condition but satisfies the boundedness condition, while $ne_n$ is the other way around.

@DavidGao thanks. Yes, good point. I think another way to put this is that $e_n/n$ is a Bessel sequence, while $n e_n$ isn't. Bessel sequences (those having an upper frame bound) are ensured to have bounded synthesis and analysis operators, while sequences missing the upper frame bound have unbounded analysis op from which the issues you point out follow. In both cases, what I find odd is: we know all vectors can be decomposed with the elements of the sequence.. and yet we simply cannot leverage the strategy via inverse frame operators to get the coefficients it seems.

@DavidGao I edited the post upon realising a few other things. I also included your example because I agree it's very natural to consider here. I found the answer to the question of analysis operator being bounded reading again about Bessel sequences (eg in Christensen 2016 book), so I somewhat changed that part. What I'm trying to understand better is not much conditions for a sequence being a frame, but what happens to decomposition coefficients and how to find them, when a sequence isn't a frame

I later also found that decompositions in terms of sequences that are not Bessel, thus corresponding to unbounded synthesis operators, is briefly discussed by Christensen  chapter 8.4 (https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-25613-9) and in their previous paper https://doi.org/10.1006/jmaa.1995.1363
